# how to convert separated list to square matrix in excel

Tags: excel, matrix

I have list which have separeted nodes, delimited with semicolon. I want to separate them and turn list into square matrix. I am trying to extract network, so need ".net" file from list's nodes cooccurences. I tried separeted them and use pivot table but not achived anything. the example what i am trying to do is in the picture below. How can i done this.

[image]

Comment: COUNTIFS() with wildcards should do what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS.  Put this in E2 and copy over and down the grid.:

```
=IF(E$1<>$D2,COUNTIFS($A:$A,"*"&$D2&"*",$A:$A,"*"&E$1&"*"),COUNTIF($A:$A,"*" & $D2 & "*" & E$1 & "*"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly, but how can i apply that if i dont know name of  nodes. in my example there is 6 node only  if i had 1million node how can i extract nodes properly and put them x and y axis.

Comment: @t.ztrk So are you trying to delimit your list of nodes from **Column A** and then create X and Y axes that contain unique - but identical - values, even if, say, *A* appears twelve times in **Column A**?

Comment: VBA will be needed to do that.